# Как остановить вывод результатов в консоли postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой, и как не странно, но не смог найти ответа на вопрос как остановить вывод результатов запроса в консоли postgres, когда результатов очень много и они выдаются пачками по нажатию enter? Закрывать консоль и заново коннектиться к БД не комильфо, но другого способа не нашёл.

Comment: Обычный `ctrl+c` не помогает?

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек. Помогло. А где-то можно почитать про полезные комбинации в shell?

Answer (score 0):

Выход из этого режима (просмотра) обратно в psql кнопкой "q".

Ctrl-c или Сtrl-z - прерывает консольный сеанс (зависит от терминала).